# Does Rails create a separate database for each application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am a beginner in Rails, trying some examples on my Windows 7 machine.

I am getting the following error : `SQLite3::SQLException: table "entries" already exists`

"entries" is a table that was already created in another Rails application, and I am trying a similar example that is trying to create "entries" again.

Does Rails create a separate database in sqlite for each application ? (I am new to Sqlite also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each application there is a `database.yml` file in config folder of your application. You can define your database name unique to your application together with your database settings. Probably you just have the same `database.yml` file for both of your projects. So your current application is also trying to create the table which is already existed(created by `database.yml` file of your previous application).

The solution is to change the `database.yml` specific to your application.

After that you can run:

```
rake db:create

rake db:migrate
```

in the above order and it will be all fine.

You can also do only `rake db:drop` and then the above two commands without modifying your any `database.yml` file but this will delete your previous database and create the new one for this application fresh. But this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when using sqlite, Rails uses databases named `development.sqlite3`, `test.sqlite3`, `production.sqlite3` which are files in the `db` directory of the Rails project.

So you'll end up using the same database if your new application is in the same folder as your old one; or if your `config/database.yml` file is pointing to some common location for the DBs.